# sum column between 2 data frames

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames with the same column, and I want the sum of the column. The problem is these data frames have different number of rows and therefor the order of the rows is different, for example:

data frame 1

| Name | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| C | 3 | 1 |
| D | 3 | 1 |

data frame 2

| Name | c1 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 4 | 1 |

I want to get this:

| Name | c1 |
| --- | --- |
| D | 4 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 6 |

Thanks!

Comment: Why is C missing in your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(across(intersect(names(df1), names(df2))[-1], sum))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Name     c1
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 B         6
3 C         3
4 D         4
```